# Is there a simple way to get all the files from a drive with two different versions of OSX both into one OS on a new system?

Tags: mac, partitioning, osx-snow-leopard, macos-sierra

Basically the title. I am upgrading computers and I don't want to run two different operating systems anymore. I am wondering if there is a way to get all the data from both onto a new computer running macOS Sierra in a simple manner like time machine or something along those lines. I essentially want all the files from both partitions to be on the same OS under a single user. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: only if you want the end result to be two users, you cannot merge them. Please add that info to your question & let's see if we can generate an answer that will help you.

Comment: Where is the PROBLEM? See my answer below. **** As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"! ****